# Access sftp folder

Tags: permissions, sftp

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server in Amazon web services, I have apache installed and a project in the `/html` folder, there is a `logs/` folder in the project, apache writes log errors and debug messages inside this folder.

I have created a user in Ubuntu which my developers will have access I want them to access only the logs folders and be able to modify its contents.

They are going to get in using `winSCP` and see the log files contents I have modified the `sshd_config` file but when I give the logs folders 755 permissions my developers are able to login using `winSCP` but apache is not able to write log files If I give the 755 permission apache is able to but developers are not able to login.

How can I achieve the solution?

Comment: Can this [blog post](https://bbkane.github.io/2017/04/25/Creating-a-shared-folder-in-Linux.html) help?

Comment: You have given two contradictory descriptions of what happens when you set the permission to 755. Who is the owner of these files?

Comment: @muclux root is the owner